# Least upper bound of a poset

Tags: multivariable-calculus, order-theory

The least upper bound property for a poset $S$ can be stated as
follows: Every nonempty subset of $S$ that is bounded above has a supremum in $S$.

This is a statement taken from a book. Now consider an example where $S=\mathbb{R}$ (Set of real numbers). Let the non empty subset be $D=[2,5]$. Now it is bounded above but it does not contain a supremum. What is wrong in this?

Answer (score 2):

The set certainly contains $\sup$, namely, $5$. Why do you think it does not contain it?

Comment: Yes, moreover, it was not necessary that the set contained its sup to have a sup. For example, we would still have $\sup[2,5)=5$.